# return evaluated javascript function to terminal

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to return a function that has been evaluated to the terminal.  I tried using `window.onload()`, `console.log();` `alert();`  but the URL isn't evaluated and sent to the terminal.

I run the code below using the command `phantomjs test.js`

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

function testlink() {
  return(["h","t","t","p","s",":","\/","\/","i","b","m",".","c","o","m"]);
}

window.onload = testlink;
console.log(testlink);
alert(testlink);
```

Instead of getting (**this is what I want**)

```
https://ibm.com
```

I get

```
function testlink() {
  return(["h","t","t","p","s",":","\/","\/","i","b","m",".","c","o","m"]);
}
```

Ps: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and phantomjs 2.1.1

Comment: It feels like you just started writing this code without reading the Phantom documentation: you've created a page, and then what? The code after that is basically meaningless: this is a test case, what are you testing? Because printing a known array to the terminal does nothing meaningful, and gives zero insight into what the page is supposed to be doing. So: what are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans trying to return an evaluated a url link that is generated using a javascript function and have it show in the terminal.

Comment: Okay, but: _why_? Because puppeteer is for running tests, and exiting with a useful exit code (and optionally, an error log if one or more tests didn't pass). The terminal should not be your method of looking in on what your tests are doing (and _certainly_ not a place you should be trying to find specific information in terms of further automation)

Comment: Also, on a sensible code note, I'd strongly recommend not using `return(["h","t","t","p","s",":","\/","\/","i","b","m",".","c","o","m"]);` but using `return "https://ibm.com".split('')`. With the related note that `return` is not a function: it's just `return`, not `return(...)`. (the latter will work, but not for the reasons you might think, so just don't use parentheses with `return`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `console.log(testlink())` instead of `console.log(testlink)`

If we want to join all the characters in that array, just return:

`["h","t","t","p","s",":","\/","\/","i","b","m",".","c","o","m"].join("")`

Or if you dont want to change the function, do `console.log(testlink().join(""))`

Comment: It was close but it gives me `h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,i,b,m,.,c,o,m
`  for the ouput.

Comment: yeah? because you're returning `["h","t","t","p","s",":","\/","\/","i","b","m",".","c","o","m"]` in that function. Idk what you expect it to do. If you want all that characters to be joined, look at my edited answer.